# What's the equivalent of Border Type in code?

Tags: macos, swift3

`NSImageView` has a property called Border Type in Interface Builder:

[image]

What is its equivalent in code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's `imageFrameStyle`:

```
imageView.imageFrameStyle = .grayBezel
```